# Why is AWS EC2 CPU usage shooting up to 100% momentarily from IOWait?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sensu

I have a large web-based application running in AWS with numerous EC2 instances. Occasionally -- about twice or thrice per week -- I receive an alarm notification from my [Sensu](https://sensuapp.org/) monitoring system notifying me that one of my instances has hit 100% CPU.

This is the notification:

```
CheckCPU TOTAL WARNING: total=100.0 user=0.0 nice=0.0 system=0.0 idle=25.0 iowait=100.0 irq=0.0 softirq=0.0 steal=0.0 guest=0.0

Host: my_host_name
Timestamp: 2016-09-28 13:38:57 +0000
Address: XX.XX.XX.XX
Check Name: check-cpu-usage
Command: /etc/sensu/plugins/check-cpu.rb -w 70 -c 90
Status: 1
Occurrences: 1
```

This seems to be a momentary occurrence and the CPU goes back down to normal levels within seconds. So it seems like something not to get too worried about. But I'm still curious why it is happening. Notice that the CPU is taken up with the 100% IOWaits.

FYI, Amazon's monitoring system doesn't notice this blip. See the images below showing the CPU & IOlevels at 13:38

[image]

[image]

[image]

Interestingly, AWS says tells me that this instance will be retired soon. Might that be the two be related?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AWS is only displaying a 5 minute period, and it looks like your CPU check is set to send alarms after a single occurrence. If your CPU check's interval is less than 5 minutes, the AWS console may be rolling up the average to mask the actual CPU spike.

I'd recommend narrowing down the AWS monitoring console to a smaller period to see if you see the spike there.

Answer (score 0):

*I would add this as comment, but I have no reputation to do so.*

I have noticed my ec2 instances have been doing this, but for far longer and after apt-get update + upgrade.
I tough it was an Apache thing, then started using Nginx in a new instance to test, and it just did it, run apt-get a few hours ago, then came back to find the instance using full cpu - for hours! Good thing it is just a test machine, but I wonder what is wrong with ubuntu/apt-get that might have cause this. From now on I guess I will have to reboot the machine after apt-get as it seems to be the only way to put it back to normal.